# JLabel-Array create on Button push

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jbutton, jlabel

I want to create a JLabel of an Array on a button push. I've **never** done something with Arrays, so maybe it's some sort of training. I tried it, but it won't work. Expected result: Everytime I push the button, would one of the 20 JLabels be created. 
Here's my class:

```
public class JLabelArray {

static JFrame frame;

static JButton button;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    final JLabel[] label = new JLabel[20];

    //
    button = new JButton("push me");
    button.setBounds(0, 0, 100, 30);
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // This is where a new JLabel should be created
            for (int i = 0; i < label.length; i++) {
                label[i] = new JLabel("Label" + i);
                label[i].setBounds(button.getX(), button.getY()+ 10 + i * 15, 50, 50);
                frame.add(label[i]);
                frame.revalidate();
                frame.repaint();
            }
        }
    });
    //

    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(500, 500);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLayout(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.add(button);

}

}
```

EDIT: Updated code
EDIT2: Updated for-loop
EDIT3: I reworked the whole question

Comment: You need to `validate()` your container after adding labels to it. From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#validate--): "*Layout-related changes, such as setting the bounds of a component, or adding a component to the container, invalidate the container automatically*"

Answer (score 0):

You should re-validate/repaint when you add Components after the parent container has been validated - this includes not only when you add the JButton (add this prior to setting the JFrame to visible) but also when you add the JLabels

```
            frame.add(label[i]);
            frame.revalidate();
            frame.repaint();
```

I would also recommend not using a null layout, rather choose the appropriate LayoutManager: see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html . If you wish to continue using a null layout, then you should set the added Labels to different positions or they will just overlap each other.

Comment: Like this? label[i].setBounds(button.getX(), button.getY() + i * 15, 50, 50);

Comment: 'Not working' is not meaningful. Do you mean the JLabels are still not visible? Works for me (aside from the overlapping part, which, in reference to your first comment above: did you try it?)

Comment: They are still invisible.

Comment: I can't see your computer screen - you should update your code with the current source code version you are compiling.

Comment: Im dumb. wrong parametre in the for loop. But still not the result, i wanted

Comment: I don't want, that every single JLabel is visible at the same time. I want it like, on every button press, one JLabel goes visible.